# :after pseudo-element not appearing

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm building a scalable mobile menu icon and the :after pseudo class is not working. This is intended to create 3 black lines to represent the "hamburger" menu icon. The first line is created, the second line is created using the :before pseudo class, however the :after pseudo class is not rendering, thus the third black line is not appearing.

JS Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/eeks1swx/

I'm not entirely sure why and I can't seem to figure it out. Any thoughts?

```css
.hamburger {
  height: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.hamburger__line:before,
.hamburger__line:after,
.hamburger__line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  top: 40%;
}
.hamburger__line:before,
.hamburger__Line:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}
.hamburger__line:before {
  top: -200%;
}
.hamburger__line:after {
  top: 200%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hamburger">
  <div class="hamburger__line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Those are pseudo-**elements** not pseudo-*classes*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
.hamburger__line:before,
.hamburger__Line:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
}
```

... you have an uppercase L - classes are case sensitive.

Comment: You're welcome - it's the little things sometimes ... I went over that a million times before I spotted it and it was really doing my head in as well.

Comment: Tell me about it. Apparently I haven't had enough coffee today haha